# how to replace specific word in a sentence with python

Tags: python, string, replace

I have a sentence for example "hello this is hello stackoverflow hello". What I need to do is keep the first hello but remove other "hello"s in the sentence. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Must be faster than Ned's one, but the price is readability:

```
>>> idx = s.find('hello') + len('hello')
>>> s[:idx] + s[idx:].replace('hello', '')
'hello this is  stackoverflow '
```

Comment: I originally used something like this in a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
parts = old.split("hello")
parts[1:1] = "hello"
new = "".join(parts)
```

Seems like there should be a better way...

Comment: FYI, spacing maybe a problem with this one.

Comment: problem is all the "hello"s may not be the same capitalization. If any of the hello's have different capitalization it wont work properly.

Comment: @incognito2. Not fair! The capitalization issue completely changes your original question.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> s = 'hello this is hello stackoverflow hello'
>>> head, sep, tail = s.partition('hello')
>>> head + sep + tail.replace('hello', '')
'hello this is  stackoverflow '
```

Answer (score 0):

Very bad way:

```
s = "hello this is hello stackoverflow hello"
s = s.replace("hello", "world").replace("world", "hello", 1)
```

It will replace all the `hello` by `world`, then replace only the first `world` by `hello`

Comment: Works great until your input string already contains "world" before "hello".

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "hello this is hello stackoverflow hello"
t = "hello"

i = s.index(t) + len(t) + 1
s = s[:i] + s[i:].replace(t, "")

print s # hello this is  stackoverflow
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, everyone will see this as a matching pattern conundrum, so the question is why does `hello` repeat?

If the first `hello` is assumed then a simple filtering of the string can fix the problem

```
s = 'hello this is hello stackoverflow hello'
l = s.split(' ')
"hello %s" % " ".join(filter (lambda a: a != 'hello', l))
'hello this is stackoverflow'
```

Or:

```
import re
s = 'hello this is hello stackoverflow hello'
re.sub('\shello\s?', ' ', s).strip()
'hello this is stackoverflow'
```

Comment: That only works if the first `hello` happens to be at the start of the string.

Comment: Exactly why I said what I said, we see this question as a pattern issue, so we try to fix it as such, but why does hello repeat in this instance?

Comment: they are random sentences typed in by whoever

Comment: The first solution fails for, e.g. `oh hello, this is hello stackoverflow hello` (it produces `hello oh hello, this is stackoverflow`).

Comment: Of course it would fail, my answer is assuming `hello` is the first word. Again this is strange pattern to attempt programmatic correction.

Comment: Apologies for labouring the point, but it also fails if `hello` is not followed by a space (e.g. the first `hello` in my example).